# Docker, where does the firewall go?

Tags: docker

I'm new to docker and am trying to understand when I build a system, does the host system need some configuration like users, ssh, firewall, fail2ban, etc.

Or does everything go into docker containers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to protect the host, since anyone that can access the host can access all the containers. Docker itself utilizes iptables and pre-configures the firewall rules for each container it spins up to allow outbound traffic but block new inbound traffic. Opening up inbound traffic would then be done by exposing a port on the host (`docker run -p ...`).